# Azure devops implementation for a E2E Streaming solution

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

I have developed an E2E sample Streaming solution using Azure Function, Azure Event Hub, Azure Datalake Gen2, Azure Stream Analytics & Power BI. I exported the templates for all of the above Azure services but not sure how to integrate them with Azure Devops. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try using this tutorial?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

> Azure devops implementation for a E2E Streaming solution

Since you have exported the templates for all of the above Azure services, you could try to add those templates files into your Azure devops repo:

[image]

Then we could deploy them by the [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template Deployment](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) Task, which is used to deploy Azure Resource Manager templates at resource group deployment scope, subscription deployment scope and management group deployment scopes. The task is also used to create or update a resource group in Azure.

You could check this document [Integrate ARM templates with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines) for some more details.